# Not able to install r- requirements.txt

Tags: python, pygame, requirements.txt

I'm pretty new to python. I am currently trying to install the requirements.txt from a program, someone wrote, because I'm interested in how it works. So, the requirements are:

pygame==2.0.0.dev10

scipy==1.4.1

Whenever I try to install them, the following happens:

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\setup.py", line 306, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\config.py", line 221, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 559, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 275, in ask
    update(x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 258, in update
    download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 107, in download_prebuilts
    download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5wijmhxv\pygame_4c7459d9ada34e90b72cf5ca2d31ce75\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 40, in download_sha1_unzip
    response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip 6839b6ec345ef754a6585ab24f04e125e88c3392
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
Downloading... https://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9d.zip:
Downloading... https://bitbucket.org/llindstrom/pygame/downloads/prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip 3a5af3427b3aa13a0aaf5c4cb08daaed341613ed

---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---

----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/87/6ffe2a745a4a1032594b3caab942edb4244d5a02d314fb8d2258e3a403fd/pygame-2.0.0.dev10.tar.gz#sha256=c4437da0c3d5e73a1f1e3c4a4313f7e8ca7eae472a1686840b1f34989ffae08a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0.dev10 (from versions: 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev4, 2.0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev8, 2.0.0.dev10, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.0.dev10
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\schne\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\schne\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-package
```

s)

Most of the time only this appears:

```
    WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/87/6ffe2a745a4a1032594b3caab942edb4244d5a02d314fb8d2258e3a403fd/pygame-2.0.0.dev10.tar.gz#sha256=c4437da0c3d5e73a1f1e3c4a4313f7e8ca7eae472a1686840b1f34989ffae08a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0.dev10 (from versions: 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev4, 2.0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev8, 2.0.0.dev10, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.0.dev10
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\schne\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\schne\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

The readme tells me:

## Super Mario Implementation in Python

### Running

- $ pip install -r requirements.txt
- $ python main.py

### Standalone windows build

- $ pip install py2exe
- $ python compile.py py2exe

I don't know why there is a dollar sign, but installing works for my only with this:

python -m

before I write the rest like pip install ...

Installing py2exe was possible, but excecuting python compile.py py2exe does not work, because for that I need SciPy.
Here is what it tells me:

```
D:\super-mario-python>python compile.py py2exe
running py2exe
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

  7 missing Modules
  ------------------
? OpenGL                              imported from pygame
? Queue                               imported from pygame.threads
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? numpy                               imported from pygame, pygame._numpysndarray, pygame._numpysurfarray
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? resource                            imported from test.support
? scipy                               imported from classes.GaussianBlur

  2 submodules that appear to be missing, but could also be global names in the parent package
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
? pygame.overlay                      imported from pygame
? pygame.sdlmain_osx                  imported from pygame.macosx
Building 'dist\main.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\users\schne\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll to dist
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_decimal.pyd to dist\_decimal.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_queue.pyd to dist\_queue.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd to dist\_elementtree.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd to dist\_tkinter.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_testinternalcapi.pyd to dist\_testinternalcapi.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_testcapi.pyd to dist\_testcapi.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_asyncio.pyd to dist\_asyncio.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd to dist\_multiprocessing.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\_overlapped.pyd to dist\_overlapped.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\base.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.base.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\constants.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.constants.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\rect.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.rect.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\rwobject.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.rwobject.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\surflock.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.surflock.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\color.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.color.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\bufferproxy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.bufferproxy.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\math.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.math.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\display.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.display.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\draw.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.draw.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\event.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.event.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\image.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.image.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\joystick.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.joystick.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\key.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.key.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\mouse.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.mouse.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\time.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.time.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\mask.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.mask.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\transform.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.transform.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\pixelcopy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.pixelcopy.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\surface.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.surface.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\pixelarray.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.pixelarray.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\_freetype.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame._freetype.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\font.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.font.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\mixer_music.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.mixer_music.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\mixer.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.mixer.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\scrap.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.scrap.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\fastevent.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.fastevent.pyd
Copy C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\imageext.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to dist\pygame.imageext.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\tcl86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\zlib1.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\SDL2_image.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\tk86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\libfreetype-6.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\libffi-7.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\SDL2.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\SDL2_mixer.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\SDL2_ttf.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\libpng16-16.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\schne\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pygame\libjpeg-9.dll to dist\
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'settings.json'
```

I've already tried to uninstall pygame, but nothing changes.
It always tells me it can't install pygame 2.0.0.dev10, because the version was not found, only the other ones like pygame 2.0.0.dev10
Futhermore, SciPy is not getting installed either. It doesn't even tries to install SciPy from the requirements.
I know, it is a lot, but I would be really happy about some help.

Comment: the `$` means that you should run the command that follows in a terminal session.

Comment: do you tried ` pip install pygame` or `pip install pygame --upgrade` in command prompt

Comment: are you using system lvl python or virtual python env with this?

Comment: @RishabhSemwal I tried `pip install pygame`.

Comment: @sahasrara62 I am using system level python.

Comment: i suggest you to creae a venv with your project and then check how it will go

Comment: Which IDE do you use

Comment: @sahasrara62 For some reason I am not able to install virtualven..

Comment: @RishabhSemwal IDLE Shell 3.9.5, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I faced this problem recently. So I installed all the libraries in my PYCHARM IDE. Now everything runs fine

Comment: Oh. It's quite difficult to code in IDLE Shell. I suggest you to install Better IDE like PyCharm. Pycharm is a beginner-friendly IDE

Comment: If you are going to install pycharm then you can install all the libraries there which I hope solve your issue. if its not then still you will not regret to use it.

Comment: Or try it once `pip install pygame --upgrade`

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Can I run the programs in PyCharm like in the IDLE Shell?

Comment: You can easily run any python program in coded form in pycharm like in IDLE shell

Comment: Is your program a ".py" file

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Upgrading Pygame doesn't work, because it is already the newest version. And I want to change to an older version of pygame.

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Yes, it is. It is saved in modules and has a main.py, which normally would start the program

Comment: Then Pycharm would be the best IDE to run this. It can also run .txt files

Comment: [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows)
download community version of pycharm from this link

Comment: @RishabhSemwal I'm already downloading PyCharm, just takes a while. If I try to run the main.py it tells my, that there is a module called "scipy" missing, so I guess I only would have to download this. But as I said, not possible. I have tried to just take the code out of the repo, but it didn't work either, since I need scipy.

Comment: sure. Tell me the result after you try it in pycharm

Comment: @RishabhSemwal I'll do it. But what do you mean with the libraries? Do I just have to move some folders into PyCharm, or what?

Comment: No. There is a separate option for installing libraries in pycharm. Libraries means pygame, scipy etc

Comment: After you finish installing pycharm. I will guide you to how to install libraries there

Comment: @RishabhSemwal So, I just downloaded PyCharm.  I can now install Plugins, but it does not tell me how to install libraries.

Comment: Run your pycharm app

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Already did it. Logged in with GitHub, opened the modules.

Comment: then go to File\ Settings \ Project \ Python Interpreter. Now Choose your python interpreter. And you also see Package - versions columns here. Click on "+" button. And then type pygame. Choose pygame then install package

Comment: Same you type other libraries here and install them

Comment: Note : must click on install to user's site package before installing the package

Comment: Open your module with Pycharm first then do all this stuff

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Ok, so I tried to install it, but it still does not work. It still tells me the same things like in the terminal. Same with SciPy.

Comment: Do you see Pygame and scipy installed in Package -- versions column

Comment: Can you send me the link of these files. I will try to do it on my pc.

Comment: No. I try to install it and it tells me:"An error occured..."

Comment: wait I have to figure out what is happening

Comment: Install pip first in pycharm

Comment: pip can be installed the same way as pygame

Comment: Doesn't pip automatically get installed with python?

Comment: I think this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnCko0NbHFI) will help you

Comment: What it is saying when you try to install pip in pycharm

Comment: Nothing as it is already installed. It shows me pip and setuptools. If I try to add it, it is shown but not possible to add.

Comment: Now it tells me, that scipy and pygame are not satisfied. I will try to install them now.
Again..

Comment: And it tells me the same again. Installing packages failed...
Which files do you mean?

Comment: Why does it has to be this compicated? I just want to run the program....

Comment: There may be some misconfiguration in your settings

Comment: Do you choose the  python interpreter when opening this file. if not choose it from upper right side of screen where code is written

Comment: Try adding pycharm to path

Comment: First time I did. Opened the file in PyCharm and chose the interpreter.

Comment: Already added it to path. I chose add to path during the installation.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you then. Recently I also encountered with the problem with pycharm. It is such a difficult problem that everyone refused to solve it. So I complained it to their developer. And they solved my problem. If you wish complain them

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Use this link to complain. Must login first with your gmail id. and then Go to new issue and write your complain. This is the last place where you complain can be solved.

Comment: I don't think that it is a problem with PyCharm. I just can't install pygame dev versions and scipy 1.4.1
Every other version works.

Comment: Since the dev versions are not ofically out and scipy 1.4.1 is an old version, my system refuses to install them.

Comment: Nevermind. Sorry for stealing your time. It obviously works with any pygame and scipy version. Just had to install scipy.

Comment: But still, this is an open question that why Pycharm refuses to install libraries. Yes try first installing scipy.Type  `pip install scipy` in cmd

Comment: I did it. I mean, everything works. The only problem was, that I couldn't install dev versions of pygame and that older scipy versions are not compatible with python 3.9.5

Comment: If you succeed in it, then comment it here

Comment: Everything is working. Like I already said, just a compatibility problem, that's not an actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your python version `3.9.5`might not be compatible with `pygame==2.0.0.dev10` or`scipy==1.4.1`

Thus try to create an environment with older python version

If you are using **Anaconda** :

`conda create --name mario python=3.7`

then

`source activate mario`

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I tried on python 3.7 and it successfully worked

### Note: Without Anaconda

you must install virtualenv

`pip install virutalenv`

Then you might need to download the python version you need ( e.g 3.7)

`virtualenv -p /path/to/any/bin/python mario`

`source activate mario`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is already fixed. It all works fine with the newest pygam, scipy and python versions. I just had to install scipy. Since the requirements say scipy 1.4.1 I only tried to install this version.